# Signed applet jar still fails for some commands

Tags: java, web-services, security, debugging, applet

I used this code to insert data to my restful web service using restful client application as follow

```
NewJerseyClient client = new NewJerseyClient();
        Prints p = new Prints();
        p.setId(235);
        p.setUsername("subhi");
        client.create_XML(p);
```

and I am using applet application and it is working without any problems ,but when I put my applet in browser these commands are not working and there is no exception.

How can I discover the problem ?!
this is the dialog that I see 
[image]

Comment: *"I signed my applet jar"*  Are you sure?  What exact dialogs do you see when it is loaded in the browser?  Also ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to open for applets and has the info. level turned up to 5.

Comment: I am sure that I have the privileges because I can writes files to the system,but what is "configured to open for applets and has the info. level turned up to 5" ?

Comment: *"but what is "configured to open.."*  I thought the first part of that was explained in the link.  The 2nd part should have been obvious after doing the first part.

Comment: BTW - I do not ask questions like *"What exact dialogs do you see when it is loaded in the browser?"* for my own amusement.  Either answer them, or I'm out of this thread..

Comment: Good edit.  Do you now understand what I meant about the console?

Comment: no I didn't understand

Comment: You'll need to be more specific.  What *exactly* do you not understand?  I do not intend trying to explain every word in the linked page!

Comment: the most important thing that I have the privileges but I cannot call the web service http://localhost:9090/test7  and there is no exception,how can I solve the problem ?

Comment: *What has your last comment got to do with viewing the console?!?*  The reason I suggested opening the console was to **get more information** on why it is failing.  Focus on that!

Comment: Are NewJerseyClient and Prints classes reside on the same jar? where your Applet resides and any of the classes in your signed jar uses a class in another jar? If so you have to sign that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using HTTP request to my restful web service so I don't have to use NewJerseyClient